# Rhomobile back function

Tags: ruby, mobile, jquery-mobile, rhomobile, rhodes

I'm having a problem getting the back button function to work in Rhomobile.

I've tried various methods of `url_for(:index, :back => ....)` etc etc and nothing seems to work. The problem with this method is (even if it worked) that it only allows navigation to a set place, rather than a dynamic history/back navigation.

The closest I've come to a working solution is by using this in the application_helper:

```
def page_back
    WebView.navigate_back
end
```

and then `<a href="page_back">Back</a>` in the view.

This works, and i can navigate across views and even controllers. However, it generates a "**Error loading page**" error, even though it does actually render the right page...

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Same issue Chris. And one more problem comes. Two consecutive Back do not occur. i.e if I try to  try to Back navigate twice, there is no back navigation for the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is what I did in the end. I've decided against using rhodes now but here is what I came up with for this problem:

Added `data-add-back-btn="true"` to:

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
```

Then:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <a href="page_back" class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
</div>
```